# Script stops working on Prestashop 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I'm trying to figure out what is the correct way of calling custom scrits on Prestashop v1.7

I've place them into **custom.js** file, script is loaded just fine and it works, but only once. As in, if I change anything on that page, click on any of the attributes, my scripts stops working.

For the life of me I can't figure out why, everything worked just fine on 1.6+ but now it won't anymore.

Script I'm using is basic jQuery click function and it's used when I click one of the attributes:

```
$("input[value='1']").click(function() {
  $("#somediv").addClass("someClass");
});

$("input[value='2']").click(function() {
  $("#somediv").removeClass("someClass");
});
```

So this click will work, but only until I click any attribute, then it stops working.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: I suppose that you don't have any javascript error. Is this element reloaded by ajax and loses the event? Can you check with `Visual event` if it has the event after first click?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the case, clicking the button will reload the element, but I'm not sure how to keep my sciprt in that scenario?

Comment: Why not using $(document).on('click',"input[value='1']",function() { ...

Comment: @DearBee please check if the element has the event with `Visual event` (http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2)